# I get undefined at start of array in js

Tags: javascript, blazor

I made this code :

```
function get_coordinates(container) {
    var x;
    var y;
    var divs = container.getElementsByTagName('div');

    Array.from(divs).forEach(div => {
        y += div.offsetTop+" ";
        x += div.offsetLeft + " ";
    });
    const a = x + ";" + y;
    console.log(divs);
    return x+";"+y;
}
```

this is the console log :

> HTMLCollection(10) [div#selector_1.selector, div#selector_2.selector, div#selector_3.selector, div#selector_4.selector, div#selector_5.selector, div#selector_6.selector, div#selector_7.selector, div#selector_8.selector, div#selector_9.selector, div#selector_10.selector, selector_1: div#selector_1.selector, selector_2: div#selector_2.selector, selector_3: div#selector_3.selector, selector_4: div#selector_4.selector, selector_5: div#selector_5.selector, …]

and this the return :

> undefined0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ;undefined0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

I dont understand why i get undefined at the start of both.

Comment: `getElementsByTagName` returns results in an array already. You don't need to run  `Array.from`

Comment: You did not initialize x and y;

Comment: @Inder if i dont put it apears this error : Microsoft.JSInterop.JSException: divs.forEach is not a function
TypeError: divs.forEach is not a function

Comment: @Musa thnx and sorry, was that

Comment: You can run a `for of` loop

Comment: @Inder lot of thanks im closely new on js :*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Musa advised in an earlier comment, you do not initialize `x` and `y`, so basically what you are trying to do is the following:

```js
y += div.offsetTop + " ";
x += div.offsetLeft + " ";
```

That translates to

```js
undefined += div.offsetTop + " ";
undefined += div.offsetLeft + " ";
```

At the top you should define that `x` and `y` are strings, for example:

```js
let x = "";
let y = "";
```

Also, I would suggest using `let` and `const` instead of `var`, it’s 2022, so no need for `var` anymore.